# How to install an app from jenkins URL with Appium?

Tags: java, jenkins, appium, appium-ios

How can I install *.ipa from jenkins url with Appium ?

```
  @Before
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Tester's mini Retina");
  capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
  capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.2");
  capabilities.setCapability("udid", "3d54a856d44eda56ea19bb7e43c155");
  **capabilities.setCapability("app", "http://10.65.5.167:8080/job/Lime%20iPad/ws/build/artifacts/LimeDemo-2.ipa");**
  driver = new IOSDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

**error:**

```
Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Bad app: 
http://10.65.5.167:8080/job/Lime%20iPad/ws/build/artifacts/LimeDemo-2.ipa. 
App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, 
or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name. cause: Error testing zip 
archive, are you sure this is a zip file? Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c 
unzip -tq /var/folders/sv/fwvlgylj26z757f6hvjgvj3w0000gn/T/116129-4973-z1mwjw/appium-app.zip`
```

Comment: i doubt the `app` path there, could you debug that `http://` thing works or not

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/jGJufdlC6F8

Comment: i can only see the count of capabilities and not there value in the screenshot

Comment: sry, like this? http://screencast.com/t/8z5F3kcZla

Answer (score 0):

Is your App signed with developer profile or distribution profile? and Appium logs would be more helpful here to figure out the problem.

Comment: I guess, the error was with the Path. It has '%20', It replaced the space with 'Lime iPad'. Try again by removing that.

Comment: problem is not this, appium can't using Jenkins URL. I am downloading .ipa Jenkins's means and using absolute app path. Ths.

Comment: The code doesn't looks like you are using the downloaded ipa. It was the path of jenkins server.

Comment: Now i do this:
**in Jenkins:** `scp "${WORKSPACE}/build/artifacts/LimeDemo-2.ipa" ~/Documents/lime_ios_tests/apps`
**in Eclipse:**
`File appDir = new File("apps");
File app = new File(appDir, "LimeDemo-2.ipa");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());`

Answer (score 0):

`info: [debug] Using downloadable app from desired caps: http://10.65.5.167:8080/job/Lime%20iPad/ws/build/artifacts/LimeDemo-2.ipa`

`info: [debug] http://10.65.5.167:8080/job/Lime%20iPad/ws/build/artifacts/LimeDemo-2.ipa downloaded to /var/folders/sv/fwvlgylj26z757f6hvjgvj3w0000gn/T/11621-4451-3ob9sk/appium-app.zip`

`info: [debug] Unzipping /var/folders/sv/fwvlgylj26z757f6hvjgvj3w0000gn/T/11621-4451-3ob9sk/appium-app.zip`

`info: [debug] Testing zip archive: /var/folders/sv/fwvlgylj26z757f6hvjgvj3w0000gn/T/11621-4451-3ob9sk/appium-app.zip`

`error: Test zip archive threw error Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c unzip -tq /var/folders/sv/fwvlgylj26z757f6hvjgvj3w0000gn/T/11621-4451-3ob9sk/appium-app.zip`

`info: [debug] Got configuration error, not starting session
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session`

`error: Stderr: [/var/folders/sv/fwvlgylj26z757f6hvjgvj3w0000gn/T/11621-4451-3ob9sk/appium-app.zip]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /var/folders/sv/fwvlgylj26z757f6hvjgvj3w0000gn/T/11621-4451-3ob9sk/appium-app.zip or
        /var/folders/sv/fwvlgylj26z757f6hvjgvj3w0000gn/T/11621-4451-3ob9sk/appium-app.zip.zip, and cannot find /var/folders/sv/fwvlgylj26z757f6hvjgvj3w0000gn/T/11621-4451-3ob9sk/appium-app.zip.ZIP, period.`

`error: Stdout: 
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Bad app: http://10.65.5.167:8080/job/Lime%20iPad/ws/build/artifacts/LimeDemo-2.ipa. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name. cause: Error testing zip archive, are you sure this is a zip file? Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c unzip -tq /var/folders/sv/fwvlgylj26z757f6hvjgvj3w0000gn/T/11621-4451-3ob9sk/appium-app.zip`

`info: [debug] Error: Bad app: http://10.65.5.167:8080/job/Lime%20iPad/ws/build/artifacts/LimeDemo-2.ipa. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name. cause: Error testing zip archive, are you sure this is a zip file? Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c unzip -tq /var/folders/sv/fwvlgylj26z757f6hvjgvj3w0000gn/T/11621-4451-3ob9sk/appium-app.zip`

```
at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/aap/Temp/Appium/appium/lib/devices/ios/ios.js:188:13)
at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/aap/Temp/Appium/appium/lib/devices/device.js:134:11)
at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/aap/Temp/Appium/appium/lib/devices/device.js:169:7)
at /Users/aap/Temp/Appium/appium/lib/helpers.js:151:11
at /Users/aap/Temp/Appium/appium/lib/helpers.js:81:7
at /Users/aap/Temp/Appium/appium/lib/helpers.js:116:9
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:220:5)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

`info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Bad app: http://10.65.5.167:8080/job/Lime%20iPad/ws/build/artifacts/LimeDemo-2.ipa. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name.`
``` cause: Error testing zip archive, are you sure this is a zip file? ``Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c unzip -tq /var/folders/sv/fwvlgylj26z757f6hvjgvj3w0000gn/T/11621-4451-3ob9sk/appium-app.zip\n)","origValue":"Bad app: http://10.65.5.167:8080/job/Lime%20iPad/ws/build/artifacts/LimeDemo-2.ipa. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name. cause: Error testing zip archive, are you sure this is a zip file? Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c unzip -tq ```
`/var/folders/sv/fwvlgylj26z757f6hvjgvj3w0000gn/T/11621-4451-3ob9sk/appium-app.zip\n"},"sessionId":null}`

`info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 111.717 ms - 936`